# How Can I modify this template to remove the blank pages and have the abstract on the title page?

Tags: templates

I'm using the following template: https://github.com/kks32/phd-thesis-template/releases/tag/v2.3.1

when I compile and run through Texstudio the pdf goes as

```
                    Title page (1)  
Blank page (2)        Abstract (3)  
Blank page (4)      Dedication (5)  
Blank page (6)  Acknowlegements(7)  
Blank page (8)
```

How can i remove these blank pages and just have double page text?

Comment: At least nobody can blame me here. Puh.

Comment: Use `oneside` in the documentclass options.

Comment: Quoting from the README: *"`oneside` or `twoside` (default): This is especially useful for printing double side (twoside) or single side.*

Comment: This is for printing on both sides of a paper sheet. Left pages (even number) are on the left. `openany` would make chapters start on any page. `oneside` just provides right handed side pages, the default for most student reports (printing on just one side of each paper sheet).

Comment: @Johannes_B the blank pages are still present, I guess it doesn't matter when I turn to printing the document? It will print on both sides of the page if i set it to twoside and i won't have any blank pages? For example when printing the title page will form the first side and the abstract will form the second side of the first sheet of paper.

Comment: If you want the back of every sheet of paper to be printed on as well, option `twoside`(default) is correct. That should leave all blank pages out. *unfortunately* .... the template makes a sily mistake here. Let me do some checks.

Comment: Funny thing is: The latest release is just seven days old. Updated because there was a question here on TeX.SX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment declaration, acknowledgements, abstract etc are typeset using an unnumbered chapter (with font commands in it, i am not very fond of that). Before \chapter* is issued, all those defined environment carry out a \cleardoulepage. That clashes with the openany option of the book class.

This might be a design decision made by the Cambridge thesis office.

You can workaround the behaviour. Please note, the main matter has to start on a right hand page. You *cannot* prevent a blank page there.

```
\documentclass[twoside,openany]{Classes/PhDThesisPSnPDF}
\let\prepareforpagenumberchange\cleardoublepage
\let\cleardoublepage\relax
\input{thesis-info}

\geometry{outer=4cm,showframe}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\include{Abstract/abstract}
\listoftables
\prepareforpagenumberchange
\mainmatter

\chapter{Wombat}
Needs to be on a right hand page, so is depending on a working
cleardoublepage
\end{document}
```

Comment: I forgot to mark up the inline code instances.  Two reputation points are in for the first <2k user that properly edits the post.